# How to write a Ruby UnitTest for a class- or module-level constant?

Tags: ruby

How does one write a test to verify a constant is present in a class or module?

Example:

```
module MyModule
  VERSION = "0.3.1"
end
```

I tried

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'shoulda'
require "my_class"

class MyModuleTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  should "have a Version constant" do
    # next two lines crash
    assert_respond_to MyModule, :VERSION
    assert_respond_to 'VERSION', MyModule
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you consider to use [**Specular**](https://github.com/slivu/specular) for more natural workflow, meant you can use any method that works in plain Ruby, thus you do not need to remember lot of extra unneeded stuff.

```
require 'specular'

module MyModule
  VERSION = "0.3.1"  
end  

Spec.new do
  check(MyModule).const_defined? :VERSION
end  

puts Specular.run


# =>   check(MyModule).const_defined? :VERSION
# =>   - passed

# => Specs:       1
# => Tests:       0
# => Assertions:  1
```

So with plain Ruby you do: `MyModule.const_defined? :VERSION`
and with Specular: `check(MyModule).const_defined? :VERSION`

not really big difference thus nothing to learn/remember/recall again and again.

Comment: Thank you @slivu! ````assert MyModule.const_defined? :VERSION```` did the trick. I will give the Specular gem a spin too. It "feels" more natural.